# IS4: Request not valid for the application's 'userAudience' configuration

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, identityserver4

I'm trying to use external login provider in my IdentityServer4. I followed the quickstart, and everything was working fine, now I'm trying to add Microsoft login.

I added this code in IS4's Startup:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddMicrosoftAccount(o =>
        {
            o.SignInScheme = IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            o.ClientId = "yadayada";
            o.ClientSecret = "yoyoyoyo";
        });
```

In the Azure Portal, I've defined the scope:

- openid
- profile

And I'm getting this error after I entered my Microsoft username/password:

**Exception:** invalid_request;Description=The request is not valid for the application's 'userAudience' configuration. In order to use /common/ endpoint, the application must not be configured with 'Consumer' as the user audience. The userAudience should be configured with 'All' to use /common/ endpoint.

**Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.**
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
IdentityServer4.Hosting.FederatedSignOut.AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

***EDIT:***
This is a bug in Asp.NET Core. Tracked here: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/19795

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error. I was able to fix it by re-creating the *app registration* and picking the *supported account type*:

- Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the manifest section in the sidebar of your app on portal.azure.com, change the value of "signInAudience": "PersonalMicrosoftAccount" to "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount" in the JSON there and save.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply go to the portal Azure panel, open the Manifest section, and change the `signInAudience`'s value from `PersonalMicrosoftAccount` to `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`. If it doesn't exist, create both key and value.